# Change data directory location with zotero standalone

Tags: zotero

I have the excellent Zotero standalone installed and pointing to a directory. I need to move the directory (to free up space) to a different hard drive. I can't seem to find any instructions for this and I'm a bit worried about messing up all the links between the references and pdfs.

How would you suggest going about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite simple:

Copy files to new location, then:

Tool -> Preferences -> Files and Folders -> Data Directory Location

Select Custom

Choose... new location

[image]

Restart Zotero

Delete old files.